# Safest, Most Performant Removal of Element with Children

Tags: javascript, dom

Assume the following markup:

```
<div id="outterParent">
    <div id="innerParent">
        <div class="children"></div>
        <div class="children"></div>
        <div class="children"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In terms of safety (avoiding memory leaks) and performance, is it OK to do something like this:

```
var outterParent = document.getElementById("outterParent");
var innerParent = document.getElementById("innerParent");

outterParent.removeChild(innerParent);

outterParent = innerParent = null;
```

...or is it better to remove each `.children` element prior to removing `#innerParent`, like this:

```
var outterParent = document.getElementById("outterParent");
var innerParent = document.getElementById("innerParent");
var child;

while (innerParent.firstChild){
    child = innerParent.firstChild;

    innerParent.removeChild(child);
}

outterParent.removeChild(innerParent);

outterParent = innerParent = child = null;
```

Comment: Your browser has development tools (profilers) with which you can measure this. E.g. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/?hl=en

Comment: @FelixKling I'm developing for iOS so Chrome doesn't really help me, but that aside, there _must_ be a best practice for this.

Comment: Safari has developer tools too ;)

Comment: @FelixKling It's a web app embedded in a webview through Phonegap, and I'm currently using a Windows machine. Pretty sure there's no way to use Safari developer tools. (And my other point stands).

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you have a reference to a child somewhere, and don't remove it, the parent can't be garbage collected.

```
var child = document.querySelector('children');
document.getElementById("innerParent").remove();
child.parentNode; // #innerParent -> it can't be garbage collected
```

So then it would be better to nullify the child reference, or remove the child:

```
var child = document.querySelector('children');
document.getElementById("innerParent").remove();
child.remove();
child.parentNode; // null -> #innerParent might be garbage collected
```

Comment: I don't think this really answers my question. Let's assume there are no outstanding references to the child elements. The question is this: When removing element A, is it best practice to _first remove element A's children_, or is it fine to just remove element A?

Comment: @West1 If you don't have references to children, I don't see any need to remove them too. Garbage collectors should be intelligent enough to remove them all. But that's implementation-dependent, of course.